# Would someone be able to migrate my question?

Tags: discussion

I don't have the requisite [250 rep](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/85041/389220) required to migrate a [question](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/16324/do-any-studies-on-long-covid-compare-to-a-control-group) to https://biology.stackexchange.com/.

Would a mod be able to do that?

Comment: IMO this is more suited to https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @user438383 good idea. I added it there: https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/q/27603/20431